# Android - Volley JSONObject Request

Tags: android, json, android-volley

So I am trying to get a specific result to show based on the choice from two spinner objects, so I get the result in the spinner objects correctly but I can't get the result of the price correctly.

This is what my spinner objects data look like

```
{
    "GetCitiesResult": [
        {
            "CityID": 1,
            "CityName": "----------------"
        },
        {
            "CityID": 2,
            "CityName": "التجمع"
        },
        {
            "CityID": 3,
            "CityName": "العاشر"
        },
        {
            "CityID": 4,
            "CityName": "القرية الزكية"
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is what my price data looks like

```
{
    "GetTripPriceResult": {
        "TripID": 0,
        "TripName": "",
        "TripFrom": "",
        "TripTo": "",
        "DayPrice": 0,
        "MonthPrice": 0,
        "TripNotes": "",
        "Stations": []
    }
}
```

I want to get the month price for a specific trip by concatenating the two string results of the selected items form the spinner objects, here's my code for getting the data and for trying to get the price, I'm not sure why the price isn't working

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG_STRING_URL = "url";
    private static final String TAG_CITY_NAME = "CityName";
    private static final String TAG_CITY_ID = "CityID";
    private static final String TAG_ARRAY_NAME = "GetCitiesResult";
    private static String TAG = HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private String tripFromSelected;
    private String tripToSelected;
    private Spinner spinnerFrom, spinnerTo;
    private TextView textView;
    private String jsonResponse;
    private Context globalContext = null;


    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }


        getCities();


    }

    private void getCities() {
        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, TAG_STRING_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        ArrayList<City> cities = new ArrayList<City>();
                        ArrayList<String> cityNames = new ArrayList<String>();



                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray(TAG_ARRAY_NAME);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject jSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String cityID = jSONObject.getString(TAG_CITY_ID);
                                String cityName = jSONObject.getString(TAG_CITY_NAME);

                                City city = new City();
                                city.setName(jSONObject.optString(TAG_CITY_NAME));
                                cities.add(city);
                                cityNames.add(jSONObject.optString(TAG_CITY_NAME));
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        spinnerFrom = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.tripFromSpinner);
                        spinnerFrom.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, cityNames));

                        spinnerFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                tripFromSelected = spinnerFrom.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });


                        spinnerTo = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.tripToSpinner);
                        spinnerTo.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, cityNames));

                        spinnerTo.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                tripToSelected = spinnerTo.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

        AppController.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
    }

    public void setText(String text){
    textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tripPriceText);
    textView.setText(jsonResponse);
    }

    public void getTripPrice() {
        String TAG_TRIP_PRICE = "http://url" + tripFromSelected + "/" + tripToSelected;
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, TAG_TRIP_PRICE, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

               try
                {
                    JSONObject getPriceResult = response.getJSONObject("GetTripPriceResult");
                    String tripPrice = getPriceResult.getString("MonthPrice");

                    Toast.makeText(globalContext, "Response: " + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(globalContext, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(globalContext, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance(globalContext).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }
```

here's my logcat

```
08-13 23:33:52.455  22127-22127/net.app.cairobus.cairobus W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 434: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
08-13 23:33:52.455  22127-22127/net.app.cairobus.cairobus W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 456: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
08-13 23:33:52.685  22127-22127/net.app.cairobus.cairobus E/Spinner﹕ setPopupBackgroundDrawable: incompatible spinner mode; ignoring...
08-13 23:33:52.685  22127-22127/net.app.cairobus.cairobus E/Spinner﹕ setPopupBackgroundDrawable: incompatible spinner mode; ignoring...
08-13 23:33:52.705  22127-22127/net.app.cairobus.cairobus I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:385>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_3.5_RB1.04.04.02.006.082_msm8974_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_3.5_RB1.04.04.02.006.082__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.06
    Build Date: 02/18/14 Tue
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_3.5_RB1.04.04.02.006.082
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
08-13 23:33:53.435  22127-22170/net.app.cairobus.cairobus D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 12(0x636169726f6275),sn(),family 0,flags 4
08-13 23:33:53.435  22127-22170/net.app.cairobus.cairobus D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo-,err=8
08-13 23:33:53.435  22127-22170/net.app.cairobus.cairobus D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 12(0x636169726f6275),sn(),family 0,flags 1024
08-13 23:33:53.435  22127-22170/net.app.cairobus.cairobus D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo-, 1
08-13 23:33:53.435  22127-22170/net.app.cairobus.cairobus D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy+
08-13 23:33:53.435  22127-22170/net.app.cairobus.cairobus D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
```

FOUND THE SOLUTION: the issue was that the method `getTripPrice()` was not called in the class, so what I did was simple, I made a button and called it inside that button's on click method.

Comment: Code looks fine. Are you getting any errors in the logcat? What are your conclusions after debugging? Which part of the code is not getting executed? And try doing getPriceResult.getInt("MonthPrice")

Comment: Okay, so even changing it to `int` didn't do anything, I will update the question with my logcat

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the problem is `AppController.getInstance(globalContext).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);` and `globalContext = null;` I can't find where you set other value for `globalContext`. Please check!

So, try to set value like the following:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        globalContext = container.getContext();
        ...               
    }
```

Comment: No the context works find, actually the issue was with the method "getTripPrice", it wasn't called anywhere, that's why it didn't get any data from the service. Thanks a lot.